# Подружить MSSQL и PHP 7+

Tags: php, sql-server

Необходимо поднять проект, написанный на ZendFramework (к делу особо не относится, проект будет переписываться). Используется MSSQL в качестве БД. Поставил драйвера для PHP (`php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll` и `php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll`). В phpinfo() показывается что sqlsrv подключен, однако:

1. PHP ругается на то, что не знает функций `mssql_*`
2. Через PDO коннект к серверу также НЕ проходит (`SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Поставщик именованных каналов: Не удалось открыть соединение с SQL Server [53]`). - на это можно забить, главное, что пытается подключиться.

**Вопрос:** как все таки наладить работу функций mssql_* в php

P.S. Ответы про настройку драйверов скидывать не нужно, в phpinfo поддержка драйвера отображается

Comment: Так там они начинаются с sqlsrv_? (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/windows/step/2.html)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov да уж, смотрю в книгу, вижу фигу - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768037/how-do-i-get-mssql-connect-to-work-using-php7 Спасибо большое. Функции mssql_* удалены в версии 7.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Функции `mssql_*` удалены с версии PHP 7+ -  https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

Рекомендуется использовать `PDO` или функции `sqlsrv_*`